# How to add Facebook Events and Birthdays to Outlook 2016

Tags: macos, microsoft-outlook, calendar, facebook, microsoft-office-2016

Since sunrise is going down soon, I'm starting to look into outlook as an alternative, as they suggest. I added my gmail accounts, but can't find a way to link my Facebook calendar with it.

I've looked everywhere. Facebook makes the webcal subscriptions available in events>upcoming, right under the "Events upcoming this week" panel, but oulook won't open them and I cannot find the option to subscribe to a calendar. Apparently this was available in previous versions so I don't see why it wouldn't be available now.

I'm also open to good alternatives for calendar apps.

Edit : Here's a screenshot 
[Screenshot of the calendar view. When clicking the "New calendar" button on the top left, Outlook creates the "On My Computer" Dropdown, with the created calendar inside, and no options available](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0n23L.png)

Answer (score 1):

- Go to Facebook
- Click on Events
- On the lower right, look for Upcoming Events
- Right-click and copy the URL

[image: Facebook Events]

- Go to Outlook 2013
- Go to Calendar
- Right Click on Calendar
- Add Calendar > From Internet
- Paste in the URL (that starts with `webcal`)

[image: Outlook Add Calendar From Internet]

The Outlook calendar should now display your Facebook events. Repeat for Birthdays.

Comment: Thank you, but my question is about Outlook 2016... Do you have a solution for that program as well?

Comment: Did you try already? What is not working in Outlook 2016 that is **not** working in Outlook 2013?

Comment: Sorry, yes In Outlook 2016 the right click on calendar doesn't show the menu, the option to add a calendar isn't available, and where it shows, the oprion 'from internet' isn't available. I'll edit my question with a screenshot

Comment: You are using Mac? I think for Mac right click requires you to hold down option or command key while you click on the mouse. It's a basic required feature. I doubt they removed it.

Comment: Yes I am, and I make sure I'm using the right click, take a look at the screenshot if you will.

Comment: I don't have outlook 2016 for Mac. I'll get back to you. I have a friend that has it installed.

Comment: Says here right-click on Mac is <kyd>Ctrl</kyd>+Click. There should be an open calendar option afterwards. http://www.officeformachelp.com/2015/01/subscribe-to-online-calendars-and-access-them-in-outlook-for-mac/